# DelphiXE8 app for Android only a limited lot of working TMediaPlayers possible?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, delphi-xe8

I made an app for Android b.m.o DEX8. It works fine. But in it I use a lot of TMediaPlayers (most of them with only very short spoken texts). Neveryheless when I use them one after the other (by touching the buttons related with them) after about 20 touches the sounds/texts can not be heard anymore...
What can be the reason for this???

Comment: Why are you using so many `TMediaPlayer` controls to begin with? Why not a single `TMediaPlayer` that you swap filenames on as needed?  You might also need to implement a queue system where the buttons put tbe filenames into a list and then you play the next file in the list when the `TMediaPlayer` finishes playing a file.

Comment: Thanks! It is the Egg of Columbus...